# Serilog MS SqlServer Sink only writing 1 log level

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I have hooked up Serilog with .NetCore and I am using the MSSQLServer sink. I can log to the database with my current setup but it seems that only one log level shows up.

**Configuration:**

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
    .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(mssql.ConnectionString, mssql.TableName, autoCreateSqlTable: true)
    .CreateLogger();
```

**Logging Code:**

```
Log.Information("Information Log");

try
{
    var numerator = 10;
    var denominator = 0;
    var num = numerator / denominator;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Error(ex, "Divided by Zero error");
}
```

The default settings will log the Information but not the error even when setting the minimum log level.

How do I change this so I can have a true minimum log level to log everything above that level to the database

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but have you tried to add selflog? 
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(msg);
                Debugger.Break();
            });

Comment: I think this might have been a bug with how serilog persisted to database, if you haven't solved this you might just need to update the serilog dll

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you use the wrong Logger. .NET Core Logging provides [extension methods](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/LoggerExtensions.cs) like `LogInformation`, `LogError`, etc (wrappers around `ILogger.Log`) that should be used:

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
    .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(mssql.ConnectionString, mssql.TableName, autoCreateSqlTable: true)
    .CreateLogger();

logger.LogInformation("Information Log");
...
logger.LogError(ex, "Divided by Zero error");
```

Comment: This is being tested in a console application. That doesn't contain the I Logger Interface.

Comment: @Dblock247 actually `CreateLogger()` method returns `ILogger`.  Again, accordingly to your sample, you creates the logger instance using [ASP.NET Core Logging](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging) but then you call some static methods  `Log.Information, Log.Error (maybe from System.Diagnostic.. or directly from Serilog package..) ` that is not what ASP.NET Core Logging provides. In other words, you use another logger, not one that you configured.

Comment: What I failed to show was Log.Logger = logger. Either way even when I user logger.Information("log message") it doesn't work. Now its not logging anything. And I know the connection string is right because it will create the database if I have autoCreateSqlTable: true.